# Does BigQuery count traffic (charge) for listDatasets(), listTables() API calls?

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery services apply [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) on API usage.
Does BigQuery count traffic of (charge for listDatasets(), listTables() API calls (no select, insert, update etc) ?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery API calls like `listDatasets()` and `listTables()` were traditionally not subject to direct billing based on the API calls themselves. These are administrative actions that retrieve metadata about datasets and tables in your BigQuery project. They are generally considered lightweight operations that do not actively process or manipulate substantial volumes of data. Consequently, they typically do not result in significant processing fees when talking about pricing. Instead, Google Cloud typically charges based on the amount of data processed by queries, storage usage, streaming data, and other factors.

These API calls are generally considered lightweight and don't directly process large amounts of data, so they might not incur significant processing charges. However, they may consume a small amount of network bandwidth. However, if these API calls are executed excessively and surpass the predefined API usage quotas for BigQuery, you may encounter rate limiting or temporary restrictions on your API usage.